# replace empty list with NaN in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace some empty list in my data with a NaN values. But how to represent an empty list in the expression?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [[1,2,3], [1,2], ["text"], []], 'y' : [1,2,3,4]})
d

    x           y
0   [1, 2, 3]   1
1   [1, 2]      2
2   [text]      3
3   []          4



d.loc[d['x'] == [],['x']] = d.loc[d['x'] == [],'x'].apply(lambda x: np.nan)
d

ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 4 vs 0
```

And, I want to select `[text]` by using `d[d['x'] == ["text"]]` with a `ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 4 vs 1` error, but select `3` by using `d[d['y'] == 3]` is correct. Why?

Comment: How is `d.x = d.x.apply(lambda y: np.nan if len(y)==0 else y)`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you wish to replace empty lists in the column `x` with numpy `nan`'s, you can do the following:

```
d.x = d.x.apply(lambda y: np.nan if len(y)==0 else y)
```

If you want to subset the dataframe on rows equal to `['text']`, try the following:

```
d[[y==['text'] for y in d.x]]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use function "apply" to match the specified cell value no matter it is the instance of string, list and so on.

For example, in your case:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [[1,2,3], [1,2], ["text"], []], 'y' : [1,2,3,4]})
d
    x           y
0   [1, 2, 3]   1
1   [1, 2]      2
2   [text]      3
3   []          4
```

if you use `d == 3` to select the cell whose value is 3, it's totally ok:

```
      x       y
0   False   False
1   False   False
2   False   True
3   False   False
```

However, if you use the equal sign to match a list, there may be out of your exception, like `d == [text]` or `d == ['text']` or `d == '[text]'`, such as the following:
[image]

There's some solutions:

1. Use function `apply()` on the specified Series in your Dataframe just like the answer on the top:

[image]

2. A more general method with the function `applymap()`  on a Dataframe may be used for the preprocessing step:

   d.applymap(lambda x: x == [])

   ```
     x       y
   ```

   0   False   False
   1   False   False
   2   False   False
   3   True    False

Wish it can help you and the following learners and it would be better if you add a type check in you `applymap` function which would otherwise cause some exceptions probably.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question, just leave out the empty lists altogether. The NaN's will automatically get populated in if there's a value in one column and not the other if you use pandas.concat instead of building a dataframe from a dictionary.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ser1 = pd.Series([[1,2,3], [1,2], ["text"]], name='x')
>>> ser2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], name='y')
>>> result = pd.concat([ser1, ser2], axis=1)
>>> result
           x  y
0  [1, 2, 3]  1
1     [1, 2]  2
2     [text]  3
3        NaN  4
```

About your second question, it seems that you can't search inside of an element. Perhaps you should make that a separate question since it's not really related to your main question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it without using `apply` (which might be slow on big DataFrames).

You can use the little trick of `.str.len()` on lists: it is initially designed to compute length of strings but also works on lists.

Combined with the `.loc[<condition>, <column>] = np.nan`, that will do the trick: `df.loc[df.x.str.len() == 0, "x"] = np.nan`

With your example, that would give:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [[1,2,3], [1,2], ["text"], []], 'y' : [1,2,3,4]})
>>> df
    x   y
0   [1, 2, 3]   1
1   [1, 2]  2
2   [text]  3
3   []  4

>>> df.loc[df.x.str.len() == 0, "x"] = np.nan
>>> df
x   y
0   [1, 2, 3]   1
1   [1, 2]  2
2   [text]  3
3   NaN 4
```