# Replace empty list values in Pandas DataFrame with NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I literarily tried every possible solution listed here and none of them worked.

I am having a dataframe which consists of dates, strings, empty values, and empty list values. It is very huge, 8 million rows.

I want to replace all of the empty list values - so only cells that contain only [], nothing else with NaN. Nothing seems to work.

I tried this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda y: np.nan if (type(y) == list and len(y) == 0) else y)
```

as advised similarly in this question [replace empty list with NaN in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818924/replace-empty-list-with-nan-in-pandas-dataframe) but it doesn't change anything in my dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think maybe it's not a problem of your code. You may check the real data type of your columns. Maybe it's default to `object`.

Comment: Are you empty lists strings `'[]'` or actual empty lists?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to assume the OP wants to convert empty list, the string '[]' and the object '[]' to na, below is a solution.

**Setup**

```
#borrowed from piRSquared's answer.
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 'hello', np.nan, None, 3.14],
        ['2017-06-30', 2, 'a', 'b', []],
        [pd.to_datetime('2016-08-14'), 'x', '[]', 'z', 'w']
    ])

df
Out[1062]: 
                     0      1    2     3     4
0                    1  hello  NaN  None  3.14
1           2017-06-30      2    a     b    []
2  2016-08-14 00:00:00      x   []     z     w
```

**Solution:**

```
#convert all elements to string first, and then compare with '[]'. Finally use mask function to mark '[]' as na
df.mask(df.applymap(str).eq('[]'))
Out[1063]: 
                     0      1    2     3     4
0                    1  hello  NaN  None  3.14
1           2017-06-30      2    a     b   NaN
2  2016-08-14 00:00:00      x  NaN     z     w
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I wanted to convert all of them to NaN's. Do you have any advice for performance? It is slow on 8 million rows. Could it be improved?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to make the assumption that you want to mask actual empty lists.

- [**`pd.DataFrame.mask`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) will turn cells that have corresponding `True` values to `np.nan`
- I want to find actual `list` values.  So I'll use [**`df.applymap(type)`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to get the type in every cell and see if it is equal to `list`
- I know that `[]` evaluates to `False` in a boolean context, so I'll use [**`df.astype(bool)`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to see.
- I'll end up masking those cells that are both `list` type and evaluate to `False`

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 'hello', np.nan, None, 3.14],
        ['2017-06-30', 2, 'a', 'b', []],
        [pd.to_datetime('2016-08-14'), 'x', '[]', 'z', 'w']
    ])

df

                     0      1    2     3     4
0                    1  hello  NaN  None  3.14
1           2017-06-30      2    a     b    []
2  2016-08-14 00:00:00      x   []     z     w
```

***Solution***

```
df.mask(df.applymap(type).eq(list) & ~df.astype(bool))

                     0      1    2     3     4
0                    1  hello  NaN  None  3.14
1           2017-06-30      2    a     b   NaN
2  2016-08-14 00:00:00      x   []     z     w
```

Comment: This is great, it works, but @Allen was right, I need to convert all of them into NaN's so I will mark his answer.